# Bootstrap 3 collapse menu not working (common issue)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with the menu for small width screens, ie, once it collapses. Nothing comes up when I click the "burger" symbol.
I've looked at most of the posts relating to this but cannot find a solution. From changing HTML, to adding CSS, to calling up a different jquery script.
I am using "bootstrap-3.3.1" framework and "jquery/1.11.2" script.
The code for navbar and scripts is shown:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top normal" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-logo" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo.svg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>


<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code works
have a look here
http://js.do/code/64123

Comment: Sorry but it does not work. The collapsed menu will not show anything. Tried on a different computer as well.

Comment: You were probably correct in this regard, see post 3 Aug 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was because my reference to "bootstrap.min" was incorrect. It should have been:

```
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Or if using links (in this case version 3.3.5):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue you need to do the following :-

Add the Jquery having version 2.1.4 , because to work with latest Bootstrap version 3.3.1 you must need to use above Jquery latest Version.

Hope after adding this jquery version your problem get solved.

Get this Jquery version from hear :-
[Jquery2.1.4](https://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: OK, also I found out why, see response 3 Aug 15.